# Validate a date on liferay

Tags: validation, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, liferay-6, liferay-aui

What is the best way to validate a date input which can be changed with text? I've tried with aui:validator with no success, when I click on the datepicker, the onSelect doesn't update the value and my custom validation recieves the old value from the datepicker.

```
<aui:input type="text" name="creationDate" id="creationDate" class="datefield">
   <aui:validator name="required"/>
   <aui:validator name="custom" errorMessage="Default error message">
        function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
            var date = new Date(val);
            var today = new Date();
            return (date < today); 
        }
    }
    </aui:validator>
</aui:input>



<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#creationDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", 0);
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#creationDate").datepicker(
    {
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function() {
            $(this).focus().blur();
        }
    }
);
```